# Javascript: how to get an element by an id?

Tags: jquery, parent

I need to get an element from its id, something along the lines of this:

```
    $(this).parent().hasId('foo')
```

How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('ID').parentNode.id
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#ID').parent().attr('id');
```

See here : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5phB/2/)

**EDIT**:

Not sure that's you asking about..

Answer (score 4):

`$("#idofelemnt")` - make sue of id selector that is will resolve issue...

```
if($("#idofelemnt").length == 0)
 alert('element not exists');
else 
 alert('element exists');
```

or in your case

```
 $(this).parent("#idofelemnt").length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get ID of parent Div in

**Javascript** as:

```
this.parentNode.id
```

and **jQuery**:

```
 $(this).parent("#foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to get element object from his id. Simply use `$('#elementId')` for getting that element object.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
if($(this).parent().attr("id")=='foo'){
    //do your stuff;
}
```